# Unable to build gradle project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, buildship

After cleaning when i try to build gradle i get an error in the console saying:

package org.json does not exist import org.json.JSONObject;

cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JSONObject

there are red marks in the java file at all places where jsonobject and json array exists.

I have put the folder web inf/lib that contains all the jar files inside the src/main/webapp directory that i have created.

currently the contents of my build.gradle file are:

```
/*
 * This build file was auto generated by running the Gradle 'init' task
 * by 'i2cdev001' at '14/11/18 3:11 PM' with Gradle 2.14.1
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Note: Also in the project properties i am unable to see any jar files under the Web App Libraries in the java build path tab. I can see only access rules:no rules defined and native library locations:(none)

Answer (score 0):

As your project is gradle project, Adding jar manually wont work.. You have to mention path where you have kept all your jar files in your build.gradle file.

Mention your jar file path in repository under flatDir {}:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
  flatDir {
   dirs 'libs'
  }
}
```

Then you have to add which jar from that folder you have mentioned above (ie libs)

```
dependencies {
  compile 'gson-0.1.0'
}
```